# What is the Cross-relation Error Method for Channel Estimation of a SIMO System?

Tags: audio, communication, signal-processing, speech

I am new to speech and audio processing and have been doing blind system identification, i.e., estimating channel parameters through channel equalisation of a SIMO audio system in the presence of reverbaration.

I keep coming across the term "cross-relation error method". I have tried to look it up on google but I am unable to figure out what this means. I have so far been able to understand that it is used for channel pairs to estimate the channel parameters, however, I haven't found a definition for it to understand it properly.

Here are some references to where I have been finding this term:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220324521_Cross-Relation-Based_Blind_SIMO_Identifiability_in_the_Presence_of_Near-Common_Zeros_and_Noise

https://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2011/papers/1569427595.pdf

I would appreciate any guidance on this topic! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where have you been coming across this term? Please link documents that refer to this term.

Comment: Right, I have added a couple of papers where I found this.

Comment: I can't fully open the first one and, the search term "cross-relation error method" does not find any hits in the second one. Neither does google find any hits on this phrase.